# Input sum issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I did an app in rails using javascript to show in another input

Here is my controller

```
 def
   @soles = Client.sum(:money)
 end
```

Here is my view ,i'm showing the result of @soles and trying to sum @soles with the value that i will write on input2 and it should show on my input sum.

The problem is that i'm getting the sum in a new page with only sum (is not showing on the input sum)

```
 <input type="text" id="my_input1" value="<%=  @soles  %>" />
 <input type="text" id="my_input2" onchange="doMath();" />
 <input type="text" id="sum" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
    var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2);
    document.write(sum);
}
```

I will really appreciate help
Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('sum').value = sum` instead of `document.write(sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.write(sum);
```

Use

```
document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
```